# How to set up a proxy via bash shell?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, proxy

I set up a proxy on Mac via `System Preferences -> Network -> Advanced -> Proxies`.

Is that possible to do the same programatically via bash shell?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, using the `networksetup` command.  There are separate options for setting different types of proxies (e.g. `-setwebproxy`, `-setsocksfirewallproxy`, etc), and you need to know the name of the primary network "service" (e.g. Ethernet, Airport... basically, the names listed in the sidebar of the Network preferences pane).  Here's an example:

```
sudo networksetup -setwebproxy "Ethernet" myproxy.example.com 8000
```

If you need to figure out the service name, use `networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder` or `networksetup -listallnetworkservices`, then parse the list to get the name of the service you want.

Answer (score 33):

You can put this in your `.profile` or `.bash_profile` or run manually on a command line:

```
export http_proxy=http://proxy.server.com:@aproxy:portnumber
export https_proxy=https://proxy.server.com:@aproxy:portnumber
```

It's also common to not use the proxy for the local connections

```
export no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,*.local
```

Comment: There are proxies that do not accept _https_ requests by themselves even though the outgoing request is an _https_ request. So you might have to `export https_proxy=http://proxy.server.com:@aproxy:portnumber` instead! (Please note the missing `s`!)

Answer (score 6):

I use this script to proxy through my ssh server (not a web proxy).

```
#!/bin/bash
disable_proxy(){
    sudo networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxystate Wi-Fi off
    sudo networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxystate Ethernet off
    echo "SOCKS proxy disabled."
}
trap disable_proxy INT

sudo networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxy Wi-Fi 127.0.0.1 9999
sudo networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxy Ethernet 127.0.0.1 9999
sudo networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxystate Wi-Fi on
sudo networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxystate Ethernet on
echo "SOCKS proxy enabled."
echo "Tunneling..."
ssh -ND 9999 000.000.000.000 -p 00000
```

Change `000.000.000.000` to your own server's IP and `00000` to your own port and you should be able to reuse it with your own ssh server. You can save this script in your home directory named say `proxy`.

Start it with `./proxy` (type your password), use `CTRL+C` to stop tunnelling.

Start it again and stop with `CTRL+C` if you forgot to stop tunnelling and next day you are wondering why your internet connection is down.

If you get a broken pipe, just start `./proxy` again.